# How to display current record's RecordType name ? (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, formula, record-type

I used this formula but it keeps displaying Contact everytime

Data Type   Formula
IF(RecordTypeId = "0123z000000KmJvAAK", "Contact",
IF(RecordTypeId = "0123z000000KmK5AAK", "Condidat",
NULL))

```
   <lightning-output-field
        field-name="Record_Typess__c" 
    ></lightning-output-field>
```

Comment: You cannot use formula directly in the HTML markup of LWC. create a JS property.

Comment: I used it setup and not ob html i just call it with lightning output field

Answer (score 3):

You can use the recordTypeInfo.name follow this code

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class WireFunction extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @track record;
  @track error;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Name'] })
  wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
      if (data) {
          this.record = data;
console.log('data.recordTypeInfo ',data.recordTypeInfo.name);
          this.error = undefined;
      } else if (error) {
          this.error = error;
          this.record = undefined;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
  import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
    import RECORDTYPEID from '@salesforce/schema/Account.RecordTypeId';
    const _FIELDS = [RECORDTYPEID];
    export default class RecordFormWithRecordType extends LightningElement {
        // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
        @api recordId;
        @api objectApiName;

        @track objectInfo;

        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
        objectInfo;

        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: _FIELDS })
        account;

        get recordTypeName() {
            // Returns a map of record type Ids 
            const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
            const rtId = getFieldValue(this.account.data, RECORDTYPEID));
            const rtInfo = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].id === rtId);
            return rtInfo.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will show me what !

Comment: I missed the LWC part. I will edit my answer in a min.

Comment: It should be `.Name` instead of `.name`, no? I haven't tried this, just asking.

Comment: @MertYALTI How to use it on HTML!

Comment: @sfdcfox according to Record Type Info class it is lowercase. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_type_info.htm#ui_api_responses_record_type_info

Comment: @Oumaima call recordTypeName in your HTML. <span>{recordTypeName}</span> you can call it like this in any part of your HTML

Comment: @MertYALTI Thanks for that. I learned something new today. I don't have a lot of experience with the ui-api.

Comment: afterRender threw an error in 'c:viewContact' [Cannot read property 'recordTypeInfos' of undefined]

Comment: `@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
        objectInfo;` and `this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;` works for me. Can you share your JS code to review?

Comment: what is the base object for this? I am confused due to name error Oumaima c:viewContact?

Comment: I am getting this error message: LWC1083: Error parsing template expression: Invalid expression { @api objectApiName;} - This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'decorators-legacy, decorators' (1:2)

Answer (score 0):

it works perfect.

ref :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info

```
getRecordTypeNameById(rtId) {
    // Returns a map of record type Ids 
    const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
    if(rtis[rtId]){
        // If found, Returns Name of record type Id
        return rtis[rtId].name;
    } else {
        // If NOT found, Return Null
        return null;
    }
}
```