# LWC @wire - Getting recordID, but no other data from the record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have what I feel like ought to be a super simple Lightning Web Component. I am showing this on a Tab in a record page for a Case.

Complete JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import IS_CLOSED from '@salesforce/schema/Case.IsClosed';
const FIELDS = [IS_CLOSED];

export default class CaseCloseForm extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', FIELDS })
        record;

    get isClosed() {
        return getFieldValue(this.record.data, IS_CLOSED);

    }

}
```

Complete HTML:

```
<template>
        Record ID: {recordId}<br/>
        Is Closed {isClosed}<br/>
</template>
```

Complete Metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Lwc Close Case</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Lwc Close Case</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

UI Output:

[image]

Note that "Is Closed" returns no information, true or false.

I know that @wire runs asynchronously so I tried updating my template:

```
<template  >
    <template if:true={record.data}>
        record.data is true
    </template>
    <template if:false={record.data}>
        record.data is false
    </template>
</template>
```

This returns `record.data is false` in the UI and does not change.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this to run on a record page in a tab? What am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. In this case, you tried to specify a parameter called `FIELDS` to `getRecord`, but it should have been `fields`.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    record;
```

When you specify a field from a variable:

```
let x = 5;
let y = { x };
```

You end up with a property of the same name and the value from the variable:

```
// y = { x: 5 }
```

Since you're supposed to all-caps a constant variable (this is definitely a good practice), you can't use the shorthand notation for the property.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, this is helpful, but I am not entirely sure I follow. I changed the value in the line from `fields: FIELDS` to `fields: fields` and now I get an error: ` [fields is not defined]`. My original post followed the pattern as specified in this this prior post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305264/how-to-display-current-records-recordtype-name-lwc - practically speaking what do I need to change?

Comment: @BobHatcher it should be `fields: FIELDS`, as in my answer. You wrote `{recordId:'$recordId', FIELDS }`.

Comment: Thank you - the line now reads `@wire(getRecord, fields: FIELDS)`, but the compiler is complaining ("LWC1503: Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis"). But I still feel like I'm missing something - in the link above, Mert Yalti does it exactly as I did in my original post and it is an accepted answer. Was my way wrong?

Comment: @BobHatcher You're missing curly brackets now. Look at my code again.

Comment: I just changed it back to `@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })` as in my original post and it is now working, I wonder if it was a browser cache issue or something else wonky going on.

Comment: thanks again. Always appreciate your help.